# Using Google cloud printing with single login

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, oauth, google-cloud-print

I am trying to print html document using phonegap plugin, it works very well. I can print the document without issues. However, I have one issue in between, every time I hit the print button I am redirected to google login screen. Since login screen opens in a inAppBrowser I am not able to save the login details.

Plugin used:
https://github.com/mohamed-salah/phonegap-print-plugin

Printing code:

```
var type = "text/html";
var title = "transaction.html";
var fileContent = "<html>Transaction</html>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Print content goes here</td>
</tr>
</table>
<body>";
window.plugins.PrintPlugin.print(fileContent,function(){console.log('success')},function(){console.log('fail')},"",type,title);
```

I am thinking that I should give access to my app via social login (gmail) or oAuth, and then may be when the popup comes up it would pick up the login details.

I am not sure how to go about that, can anyone suggest how to handle this situation?

Logging in every time I need to print is becoming a pain.